# Mouse position in dragBoundFunc

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I'm using [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/) to draw some widget on a canvas. This widget is 600px wide and is composed of several rectangles (24 by default). On this rectangles an other one can be dragged, let's call it "cursor".

Instead of a smooth drag, i want the cursor to jump to the other rectangles only when my mouse is far enough (like a stepped drag if you prefer).

For example if the cursor is at 0,0 and i have a total of 24 rectangles , i want my cursor to move to the next rectangle only when my mouse is at 25,0  (600px / 24 rectangles = 25px).

So to do that i have implemented :

```
cursor.setDragBoundFunc(function(pos){
    var caseSize = WIDTH / caseNum;
    var posX = Math.round(pos.x/caseNum) * caseSize;
    if(posX > (WIDTH - caseSize)) {
        posX = WIDTH - caseSize;
    }

    if(posX < 0 ) {
        posX = 0;
    }

    return {
        x: posX, 
        y: cursor.getAbsolutePosition().y
    }
});
```

The problem is `pos.x` does not represent the mouse position in the canvas but the mouse position from the start of the drag event (pos will be 0,0 even if i start dragging from middle of the canvas).

Here a example of the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/H9rpz/

How can i get the mouse position in the canvas in `setDragBoundFunc()` ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: `console.log(pos)` to log the contents of `pos` to your browser. Then you can inspect the object and see if it contains what you're after.

Comment: @Shmiddty : Here is the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H9rpz/. look a the console to see the value of pos.x. if you start dragging the blue rectangle by click in the right part of it , pos.x is at 0

Comment: I meant to log the whole `pos` object, in case it contained more variables. But it didn't, just x and y...

Comment: also, it looks like you're creating a new layer every time you call `draw`, which results in a new canvas in the DOM.

Comment: @Shimiddty , thanks for advice about layers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `setDragBoundFunc` function accepts two arguments and the second is an `event` object that might contain what you're after:

```
cursor.setDragBoundFunc(function(pos, event){
   var posX = event.offsetX;
   ....
});
```

You also have a math logic error at the beginning of the function. It should read:

```
cursor.setDragBoundFunc(function(pos, event){
   var caseSize = WIDTH / caseNum;
   var posX = event.offsetX;
   posX = Math.floor(posX /  caseSize) *  caseSize; // This right here
   ...
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/H9rpz/3/

Comment: `floor` is probably more appropriate than `round`

Answer (score 2):

This exact feature has been implemented in a KineticJS manual test.  Here's the code you're looking for:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/tests/js/manualTests.js#L1004

Give it a try :)

Comment: Too bad i didn't see it before ^_^ , i will investigate more on the github repo , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jan's answer, your math is a bit off:

```
cursor.setDragBoundFunc(function(pos, event){
    var posX = event.offsetX;
    posX = Math.floor(posX/WIDTH * caseNum) * caseWidth;
    ...
```